# Notepad++ remove all lines with a specific character 2 times

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a text file more than 25000 lines and want to remove those lines which have 2 or more @ sign.

Answer (score 1):

Just mark lines containing 2 at-signs and then remove them:

1. Open **Mark** dialog box (menu **Search** > **Mark...**)
2. Use these settings:

   - Find what: `@.*@`
   - Mark line: **checked**
   - Search mode: **Regular expression**
   - "**.** matches newline": **unchecked**
3. Press button **Find All**
4. Menu **Search** > **Bookmark** > **Remove bookmarked lines**

Comment: Actually, it is Search > Mark, not Edit > Mark.

Comment: @FleetCommand – exactly. When composing the answer, I read Seach and wrote Edit. Thank you.

Comment: @Jayant – Welcome to the [su]. Please mark the best answer by adding green check mark on its left side.